# Conditional providers connection

Tags: angular

I kinda new in Angular. I recently joined the project where Auth Interceptors were conditionally connected depends on environment. It worked good on JIT compilation, but since i try to move project on AOT compilation, authorization crashes with 401 Error. It seems like that Interceptor doesn't work

Actually i don't understand where to dig because environment.isSbrf returns false

```
/*imports here*/

let providers: Array<any> = [
  { provide: AuthService, useClass: AgentAuthService },
  { provide: WorkflowStateService, useClass: AgentWorkflowStateService },
  /*other providers here*/
];

console.log(environment);

if (!environment.isSbrf) {
  providers.unshift({ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true });
  providers.unshift({ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthAgentIdInterceptor, multi: true });
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ServicesModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AuthModule,
    /*other modules here*/
  ],
  providers: providers,
  declarations: [
    /*components here*/
  ]
})
export class AgentModule { }
```

i expect i will receive token from local storage in Auth interceptor like i do working with JIT compilation, but it doesn't work with AOT.

Answer (score 0):

I think it had been resolved make sure you have latest version of angular see the issue in github
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18293